# Read file from last document read - JSON stream

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stream

I'm receiving a stream from a server, that is increasing exponentially. and I need to check every minute for new data, process that data, and ask for more next minute.

the data is JSON documents. receive in average ~600-700 documents per minute.

I have to avoid reading the documents already processed due to performance issues.

Is it possible to only read the data received from the last minute?

Comment: What do you mean by _file_ and _document_?

Comment: log file with 100 JSON documents.

Comment: Well, I guess you keep track of the offset somewhere and jump to that position the next time you start reading. I don't think I understand your situation.

Comment: I will try to explain another way.
I'm receiving a stream from a server, that is increasing exponential. and I need to check every minute for new data, process that data, and ask for more next minute.
the data is JSON documents. receive in average ~600-700 documents per minute.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Edited the question for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a circular buffer and put there the data using a listener.
As an example, by storing there the last N documents or chunks, it mainly depends on the code of your application.

This way older data will be discarded for design and you have not to deal neither with streams' internals nor with poorly designed solutions.

It's a matter of defining the right size for the buffer, but it looks to me as a far easier problem.

Comment: I think I got it but a new to node.js and js, 
if the buffer reads only 3,5 documents. the last document isn't read and it will be used on next chunk right?

at the moment I have this. for testing my file doesn't not increase.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206017/node-js-stream-timer-recursion

Comment: Indeed in the circular buffer you can put the stream object, attaching to it nothing more than an handler for the error event. Once you decide to pop a stream out of the buffer to discard it, simply set to null or replace the item at the position, otherwise pop it and attach to it the listeners aimed to read the data. This way you won't waste your time dealing with data and end events you are not interested in.